How long will Dell Memtest86+ V7 32 GB Ram - Run?
I am on Pass 8. The test has been running for 15 hours. How long will this run? How to stop these test?

If we are talking about normal Memtest86 or its common derivatives, it will run forever, so stop it when you are satisfied with your results.

Unless "Dell Memtest" is special...
With default settings:

How long; as long as you allow it to run
Hit Esc, or turn off your computer.

